# Can i get an automatic email every time someone logs in to password protected directory?

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have a VPS server with WHM and cpanel.
We have a few password protected directories(defined in cpanel). We wish that whenever a user logs in to one of them, we will get an instant email.
Possible?
Thanks

Comment: I imagine that will be very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use the mail() function in PHP on your index.php. Other than that, it isn't possible unfortunately.